# Git alias to prefix personal repo information automatically on clone?

Tags: bash, git, zsh, alias

I would like to write an alias, either in git or in bash/zsh, which allows me to automatically prefix all my personal information to clone one of my repos. That is to say, where I type:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:<username>/<repo>
```

I would just type

```
$ git <alias> <repo>
```

or

```
$ <alias> <repo>
```

and the alias would take care of the rest.

I have tried doing this with git alias and I have tried doing this with a regular zsh alias, neither of them expanded properly. I was thinking maybe I could try a function, but I haven't gotten that far (I'm not very good with BASH).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this automatically with Git's URL rewriting feature.  You can add something like this to your `.gitconfig`:

```
[url "git@github.com:bk2204/"]
    insteadOf = gh:
```

Then, just clone with `git clone gh:repo.git` and everything works.  Best of all, if you later decide you'd rather use HTTPS, you can do that by just swapping the URL.